# Lookup columns into document template

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, lookup-column, document-template

I've a DocLib with the lookup field *Field01* and I want to display the associated lookup columns as *Field01:FieldA, Field01:FieldB*...

I already have them on the view, now I want the exact same behaviour but reflected on the template document. Is possible?

I've find a workaround using workflow to sync the values into normal columns. But I want to avoid this way...

spregards